# img src="..." inside html file doesn't work in android studio

Tags: android, html, image, base64

How can i handle the image src in android studio to put inside html file ?
I tried to convert the image to base64 and put it in the img src but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use HTML.fromHTML with the implementation of `Html.ImageGetter`.

**For Example**

```
Html.fromHtml(content, new Html.ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(source, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);                
        return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    }
  }, null);
```